# Redux Reducer State Not Updating Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react app, I have two components(personal items list and random items list). In my random items list component, I can click on the item and add it to my personal items list component. However, when I do that it replaces my other items in my personal items state with the new item I just added. I simply want to add on to my personal items list.

```
//Update Items List
export const updateItemsList = (data) => ({
  type   : UPDATE_ITEMS_LIST,
  payload: data
});
```

```
//Items List Reducer
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case UPDATE_ITEMS_LIST:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```
//Select Item To Add
export const addItemToList = (itemId) => (dispatch, getState) =>{
  const config = {
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  axios.post(`/api/items/addItem/${itemId}`, {}, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
      type: ADD_ITEM_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    })
   dispatch(updateItemsList(res.data, ...getState().itemsList.items));
  })
    .catch(err =>{
      dispatch({type: ADD_ITEM_ERROR}));
    });
};
```

```
//React User's Item List Component
class Items extends Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.userItems();
  }
    render(){
      const { items, loading} = this.props.itemsList;
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
        {loading === true ? (
          <div>
            <div>
            <h1>Your Items Are Loading...</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        ):(
          <div>
          {items.map(item => (
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div>
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
          </div>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Items);
```

```
//React Random Item List Component
class RandomItems extends Component{

  handleAddItem = (id) =>{
    this.props.addItemToList(id);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getRandomItemsList();
  }

    render(){
        const { randomItems, loading} = this.props.randomItemsList;
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          {loading === true ? (
            <div>
              <div>
              <h1>Loading Random Items...</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          ): (
                <div>
                {randomItems.map(item => (
              <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div>
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                <button onClick={this.handleAddItem.bind(this, item.id)}>Add To List</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
            </div>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>

      )
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(RandomItems);
```

Comment: I think this might be the error: dispatch(updateItemsList(res.data, ...getState().itemsList.items)); inside the third block of code. Perhaps you meant: dispatch(updateItemsList([res.data, ...getState().itemsList.items])); ? Another method would be by modifying the reducer.

Comment: Okay that worked in terms of adding on to the state and not replacing the other items in the state but it added the div component with no data

Comment: What does the function that componentDidMount calls do?

Comment: Okay I figured it out. res.data was coming in as an array so i had to change it to: dispatch(updateItemsList([res.data[0], ...getState().itemsList.items])). Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `res.data` is the new item you just added, when you dispatch updateItemList I think you missed the square bracket for the array. so you just sending `res.data` in the payload. it should be like this

```
updateItemsList([res.data, ...getState().itemsList.items])
```

Comment: Okay that worked in terms of adding on to the state and not replacing anything but it added the div component with not data

Comment: Okay I figured it out. res.data was coming in as an array so i had to change it to: dispatch(updateItemsList([res.data[0], ...getState().itemsList.items])). Thank you so much for your help